Best Approach for Precise Point Localization
I'm currently working on a simulation for localization in MATLAB. In my setup, I have an unknown point and three known points in a triangular arrangement. I know the distances from the unknown point to each known point. However, these distances have some error range from 1mm to 5 mm.
I'm now solving the 3-distance equation to find the location of the unknown point. To improve the precision of the point location, I've tried taking multiple distance measurements and averaging them. However, I'm still not getting the precision I need. The estimated point distance is reasonably acceptable, having less error, but the angle of the estimated point has so much deviation.
I'm looking for suggestions on the best approach or algorithm to find the precise location of the unknown point, given that distances have errors. Is there a more effective way to handle the distance errors or a different method that could provide more accurate results?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

After taking multiple measurements instead of averaging you can use the median value. This way the extremely distorted measurements won't affect your final result while they will have an effect on the average.
